# Flow Logs for AWS Transit Gateway Attachment

Tags: amazon-web-services

I want to get flow logs for traffic flowing through my AWS Transit gateway.
AWS [Documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/transit-gateway/features/) says "you can use Amazon VPC Flow Logs with AWS Transit Gateway to capture information about the IP traffic going through the AWS Transit Gateway Attachment"
But I can find no configuration in the Transit Gateway Attachment configuration page to create flow logs.
I could create flow logs from the VPCs where the Transit Gateway connects but that is not very convenient especially since those VPCs are within the accounts managed by other teams.
How do you create flow logs for a Transit Gateway Attachment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have the ENI ID of your transit gateway? There's a good chance that if you have VPC-Level flow logs turned on, and that ENI lives within the VPC that's flow logging, the logs are already being generated and pushed to your CWL.

Comment: Thanks Rajat. Yes the transit gateway creates an ENI in the attached VPC subnet and, yes, we could generate flow logs from there. However, since the VPC lives in another AWS account I would have to ask the administrator of that VPC to create the flow logs for me. I was hoping that I would be able to generate flow logs from the Transit gateway that lives in my account without having to seek permission from the other admin. I can see that I am hoping for too much. Thanks again.

Comment: Yes you can do this now with a "subscription filter" in cloudwatch logs: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-facilitate-data-analysis-and-fulfill-security-requirements-by-using-centralized-flow-log-data/

Answer (score 0):

Update:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/introducing-vpc-flow-logs-for-aws-transit-gateway/

Transit Gateway natively supports Flow Logs now. You should be able to generate flow logs for you TGWs as a whole or pick and choose the attachments to monitor. It will also populate the TGW specific identifiers in the log.